# How to use else statement with ajax in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was using the javascript code

```
function ajax()
 {

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   else
   document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML='Loading';
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET",'welcome.html',true);
xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

In this code during page processing browser prints loading.
But now Iam using
 `$('#mydiv').load('welcome.html');` 
and i don't know how to print loading while page processing in jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
$( '#mydiv' ).html( 'Loading...' ).load( 'welcome.html' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would setup #mydiv to contain the text/loading image before calling 'load' in the JS, this content will then be replaced with 'welcome.html' after it's loaded.

You could use this as part of the handler/function which triggers the load e.g:

```
$('mybutton').click(function() {

    $('myDiv').html("Loading ... ");

    $('myDiv').load('welcome.html');

});
```

or something along those lines

Comment: @sime Vidas has given better answer

Comment: Yes true, I wrote that before that answer was posted though, and being it pretty much the same answer with the same effect there didn't seem much point in removing it